# write a vhdl process to model a 4 by 2 encoder with registered output and reset

Tags: vhdl

I am confused by what the registered output means. I know how to code an encoder in VHDL, but don't know what the questions means by registered output.

Comment: well, do you know what a register is, and how to write one in VHDL?

Answer (score 0):

Registered means stored, in a flipflop. Imagine combinatorial logic:

```
A = B and C
```

When B or C change, it takes a finite amount of time for A to reflect this change. A small amount of time indeed, which quickly increases as the complexity of this logic increases. If B and C themselves would depend on a bunch of other combinatorial (and, or, xor, whatever non-clocked) logic, they wouldn't change simultaneously, A might toggle a few times before reaching its final state and worst of all, it would get difficult to predict when A would reach that final state. Certainly when considering all possible effects altering the time required by the logic, e.g. temperature. The longer the combinatorial chain, the greater becomes the influence of temperature.

That is why we restrict the length of combinatorial chains and clock the result in a flipflop to resynchronize intermediate signals so to have a predictable, well-behaving system.

A registered output means that the output is driven by a flipflop and one does not need to worry about any combinatorial logic on that path. The result comes out withing the delay specs of that flipflop after a clock edge and the variation due to temperature/voltage/process will be as good as it gets